# Highcharts - TypeError: Cannot read property 'isResponsiveOptions' of null

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, null

I have a simple chart built using highchart,
when trying to display one series it works well, but when trying to display two different series, i've got this exception, although i don't have any properties for `responsive` passed to the chart object.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isResponsiveOptions' of null
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @M1M6, Could you reproduce that issue in some online code editor? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Comment: Just got back to it, the issue is, i was update the chart object to null before rendering multiple charts, in case of multiple charts they will respond to the container size, so they will be responsive, so just removing the null and setting empty object {} solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got back to it, the issue is, i was update the chart object to null before rendering multiple charts, in case of multiple charts they will respond to the container size, so they will be responsive, so just removing the null and setting empty object {} solved the issue